# run "docker pull" action, got some ERROR related with manifest

Tags: docker, containers

When I run:

```
docker pull 2711884589/hahashao
```

I get this error:

```
Trying to pull docker.io/2711884589/hahashao:latest
Error: initializing source docker://2711884589/hahashao:latest: reading manifest latest in docker.io/2711884589/hahashao: errors:
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
unauthorized: authentication required
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are trying pull from a private repository and you must login first.
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login

Comment: I'm sure I do login. then I logout, and login again, got the same error

Comment: this may happen due to non-existance of the "latest" tag as well. please check tags and try another one

Comment: thanks, it is fixed. that is because maybe docer.io did not display all tags in real-time. I donot konw why it delay to display that. I got the latest tag on next day when I log docer.io at next day. maybe some block this site to china

Comment: @li-da-tong your welcom please accept my answer